# when i compile it, the cost shows '0' even though i put specific cases for all facilities, this is the only part i'm stuck on

Tags: java

```
int luxurc,foodc,vegc;
switch(luxur)
{
    case"economy": luxurc=20;
    case"business": luxurc=40;
    case"first": luxurc=60;
    default: luxurc=0;
}
switch(food)
{
    case"yes": foodc=3;
    case"no": foodc=0;
    default: foodc=0;

}
switch(veg)
{
    case"veg": vegc=1;
    case"nveg": vegc=3;
    default: vegc=0;
}

int df= luxurc+foodc+vegc;
System.out.println("TOTAL AMOUNT TO BE PAID: "+df);
```

Comment: You forgot the break statement in every case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a break statement after every case.If you dont add a break statement then the code will go till end.

```
switch(luxur)
        {
            case"economy": luxurc=20; break;
            case"business": luxurc=40; break;
            case"first": luxurc=60; break;
            default: luxurc=0;
          }
          switch(food)
          {
              case"yes": foodc=3; break;
              case"no": foodc=0; break;
              default: foodc=0; 

          }
          switch(veg)
          {
              case"veg": vegc=1; break;
              case"nveg": vegc=3; break;
              default: vegc=0;
          }
```

Comment: thank you very much, it was a silly mistake :)